# Android coverflow with text

Tags: android, coverflow

I have implemented a coverflow using images.Now I want to place text below all the image in the coverflow. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create your custom coverflow in android. See [custom coverflow](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

- Now all you need is an activity to instantiate the Coverflow in it's
  onCreate method. It also has an internal Class, ImageAdapter which we
  use as the adapter for the Coverflow widget, much as we would for a
  Gallery widget. It is also possible to use the Coverflow widget when
  it is specified in an XML layout file. create a view having one image
  view and textview to the below of image view pass that view to the
  adapter